# ReactJs with big forms, having a lag when type in text fields

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a React JS application. It has a quite big form with more than 25 fields in it. When typing in text fields it is delaying the type, seems like having a small lag.

I am using a function component and use "usestate" hook to mange state data.

Any reason for this and any way to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.
Darshani

Comment: It's because every keystroke is probably causing the entire form to re-render. Without looking at your code it's hard to tell what's causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
<input
  className="form-control"
  type="text"
  name="name"
  defaultValue={form.name}
  onBlur={onChangeHandler}
 />
```

This only triggers an event on blur and prevent re-render on each change. It's useful since when you click on any other button to process the data, it's guaranteed that you'll have the updated state.

- You can also try and make a **multi-setup form**
- This problem is related to the components you are rendering while changing the value. Using react developer tools you can easily check how many components render on change of your input field.